# How to get the lvalue of GetElementInst, AllocaInst or LoadInst in LLVM?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm wondering how to get the lvalue of a `GetElementInst` or `AllocaInst` in LLVM.

The IR is as follows:

```
%b15 = **getelementptr** inbounds %class.M* %c, i32 0, i32 2
%b16 = getelementptr inbounds %class.B* %b15, i32 0, i32 1
%6 = **load** i32* %b16, align 4
%add17 = add nsw i32 %6, 10
%b18 = getelementptr inbounds %class.M* %c, i32 0, i32 2
%b19 = getelementptr inbounds %class.B* %b18, i32 0, i32 1
```

I need to analyze the IR. I want to know if there is any way to get the lvalue of the `GetElementInst`, `AllocaInst` or `LoadIns` because I have to analyze the relationship between all the register values.

Hoping for your help!

---

### Detailed description

In fact I want to track all the objects' store counts and load counts.

To this end, I traverse all the Instructions to get the load & store information. But in the LLVM IR as followers, the first 3 instructions just represent a load operation of the `%class.M* %c`.

In brief, for a `GetElementPtrInst` such as `%b16 = getelementptr inbounds %class.B* %b15, i32 0, i32 1`, I want to get the conclusion that `%b16` belongs to `%b15`.

```
%b15 = getelementptr inbounds %class.M* %c, i32 0, i32 2
%b16 = getelementptr inbounds %class.B* %b15, i32 0, i32 1
%6 = load i32* %b16, align 4
%add17 = add nsw i32 %6, 10
%b18 = getelementptr inbounds %class.M* %c, i32 0, i32 2
%b19 = getelementptr inbounds %class.B* %b18, i32 0, i32 1
```

My Function for traversing all the Instructions:

```
virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
    //errs() << "Begin" << "\n";
    errs() << F.getName() << "\n";
    char OpName[256];
    char OpType[256];
    for (auto &BB : F) {
        for (auto &I : BB) {
           /* if (auto *op = dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(&I)) {
                errs() << "allocaInst" << "\n";
                Value *OpV = I.getOperand(1);

                strcpy(OpName, OpV->getName().str().c_str());
                //get operand type
                auto *type = I.getAllocatedType();
                std::string typestring;
                raw_string_ostream S(typestring);
                type->print(S);
                S.flush();
                strcpy(OpType, typestring.c_str());
                createCallForParameterLine(op, 1, OpName, OpType, OpV);
            }
            else*/ if (auto *op = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(&I)) {
                errs() << "storeInst" << "\n";
                Value *OpV = I.getOperand(1);
                if (OpV->hasName() /*&& OpV->getType()->getTypeID() == 14*/) {
                    strcpy(OpName, OpV->getName().str().c_str());
                    //get operand type
                    auto *type = OpV->getType();
                    std::string typestring;
                    raw_string_ostream S(typestring);
                    type->print(S);
                    type->print(errs());
                    S.flush();
                    strcpy(OpType, typestring.c_str());
                    createCallForParameterLine(op, 1, OpName, OpType, OpV);
                }
            }
            else if (auto *op = dyn_cast<LoadInst>(&I)) {
                errs() << "loadInst" << "\n";
                Value *OpV = I.getOperand(0);
                if (OpV->hasName() /*&& OpV->getType()->getTypeID() == 14*/) {
                    strcpy(OpName, OpV->getName().str().c_str());
                    //get operand type
                    auto *type = OpV->getType();
                    std::string typestring;
                    raw_string_ostream S(typestring);
                    type->print(S);
                    S.flush();
                    strcpy(OpType, typestring.c_str());
                    createCallForParameterLine(op, 2, OpName, OpType, OpV);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[EDITED to better match OP' question]**

You can have operands of any instruction simply by calling `getOperand(0)` on the underlying `User` of the instruction.

On specific instructions, such as `LoadInst` or `GetElementPtrInst`, you have numerous other methods, such as `getPointerOperand`.

Those methods are declared in Instructions.h in your llvm code base.

Anyway, this will return you a `Value`, which you can the process.

for example, on :

```
%b16 = getelementptr inbounds %class.B* %b15, i32 0, i32 1
```

inst->getPointerOperand will return you %b15. If you need %b16, it's simply the Value you're processing.

Here is an example of code trying to perform what you want **[Not tested]**:

```
std::map<Value*, Value*> result;
for(auto &BB: F)
{
  for(auto &I: BB) 
  {
    switch(I.getOpcode()) {
      case Instruction::GetElementPtr:
        llvm::GetElementPtrInst* gep = llvm::dyn_cast<GetElementPtrInst>(&I);
        result.insert(std::pair<Value*, Value*>(&I, gep->getPointerOperand());
        break;
      //.. TODO other cases
    }
  }
}
```

then you can process your map of dependencies to display names appropriately.

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Sorry, i'm confused about "If you need %b16, it's simply the Value you're processing" .          In fact, I want to get the relationship between %b15 and %b16.           That is to say, I want to get **both %b15 and %b16** according this instruction.           So is there any way to get these values?

Comment: %b16 is the instruction itself, %b15 is it's first operand. Or I don't understand what you mean by "value"

Comment: In my opinion, %b15 and %b16 are register values, and I can get their names using `Value::getName()`. What Iwant is to find their relationship.      for example , on : `%b15 = **getelementptr** inbounds %class.M* %c, i32 0, i32 2
%b16 = getelementptr inbounds %class.B* %b15, i32 0, i32 1
%6 = **load** i32* %b16, align 4
%add17 = add nsw i32 %6, 10
%b18 = getelementptr inbounds %class.M* %c, i32 0, i32 2
%b19 = getelementptr inbounds %class.B* %b18, i32 0, i32 1`

Comment: I'm confused. Could you please share the code you already have?

Comment: I have changed my Question description, and sorry for the wrong operation.